# MySQL Change column value to the least value in its category

Tags: mysql

Assuming only one school can be identified in a specific town, you are required to move students from duplicated schools to originally created schools. We also assume that lowest school id implies the first schools to be created in
the database, hence original schools.

I want to achieve this simply by changing the school ids for duplicate school+town to the smallest school id (the original) in that category. This will take care of the student records table that is linked to this one via foreign key (school id).

How would I go about doing this on the table attached? I'm thinking along the lines of SELECT MIN, CASE STATEMENTS as well as GROUP BY and COUNT() but I'm at a loss on how to combine these. Anyone have an idea/code on how I would achieve the requirement above?

[image: Database Table]

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  Also, please include the output you expect.

Comment: Adding to the above comment, the phrasing in the first sentence "*you are required to*" makes me think this is a school / university assignment, so we'd expect you to try even **more** than you would for a non-assignment question.

Comment: I'd assume that the school id is unique identifier (key). Therefore you can't just update it in the `schools` table. You'd rather need to update the `school_id` in the students table to point to the original school's id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume that the school id is a unique identifier (key). Therefore you can't just update it in the schools table. You'd rather need to update the `school_id` column in the `students` table to point to the original school's `id`.

If this is the case you can do something along the lines of

```sql
-- get all students and their current school info for update
UPDATE students st JOIN schools sc        
    ON st.school_id = sc.id JOIN (
  -- get ids of original schools 
  SELECT town, name, MIN(id) id
    FROM schools
   GROUP BY town, name
) q -- join students with a list original schools ids
    ON sc.town = q.town AND sc.name = q.name
   -- change the school id to the original one
   SET st.school_id = q.id
   -- but only for students that were associated with non-original schools     
 WHERE st.school_id <> q.id
```

Here is [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=aff23e551246462d1a34a1b3bddebf54) demo

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks perterm. I have much to learn on MySQL; turns out I've just scratched the surface.